# Different results after training my model

Tags: time-series, validation

I am using Keras to train a `Conv1D` model to solve a timeseries forecast problem. In this problem, i need to forecast a variable `x` wich has hourly measurements. I have split my whole dataset into train/validation/test sets. During training/validation, i am using MSE as loss function and in the test phase, i am using MAPE.

I am using a `for` loop to train the model 10 times for statistical assessment of performance (using the same train/val sets at each iteration). So, for validation, i have a `val_loss` looking like this at each initialization (i am using `tanh` as activation function in all layers of my model):

[image]

I picked up the model with the lowest MSE (i.e, the model at initialization 5), and used my test set in it.

In the test phase, i am forecasting hourly values of `x` and separating those predictions into months. And i got at each month MAPEs like this:

[image]

I did this same experiment a few more times and i always get similar resulsts in the validation data (around 0,0006). But, sometimes, i am getting different MAPEs results in the test set. These differences vary by up to 0.4% in the average MAPE (wich is really high in the related area of my problem).

Some things to note:

1 - I am training my model with normalized data (`MinMaxScaler` between 0 and 1). The `val_loss` showed here is in that scale;

2 - When calculating the MAPEs, i have reverted the data to the original scale using `scaler.inverse_transform`.

3 - I did this experiment 5 times. Two of them i get the same result in both validation and test. But in the other three, i am getting the differecens in the test set.

What could be causing this difference in my MAPE? If i need to provide any aditional information, please let me know.

Comment: Due to random initialisation Keras models are not reproducible out of box.

Comment: @patagonicus Sorry, but what do you mean by that?